# What purpose do the coloring bounds of the affine subspaces serve in Mead's theorem (Lemma 2)?

Tags: coloring

I'm researching topics for an Extended Essay--and I've decided on Monsky's theorem and analyzing the dimensional generalization (Mead's Theorem). I'm stuck on Mead's usage of affine subspaces and the coloring bound he sets...

"Lemma 2. Consider a decomposition of an n-polytope $R$ into simplexes in
which each vertex is labeled $p_{¡}$, $0 < i < n$, and such that any $k$-dimensional
affine subspace which contains vertices labeled $p_{¡}$, for all $0 < i < k$ contains no
vertex labeled $p_{i}$ with $i > k$. Then the number of complete $n$-simplexes is odd if
and only if the number of complete $(n-1)$-simplexes on the boundary of $R$ is
odd." (Mead)

Could anyone clarify in detail why Mead uses the bound?

Thank you!